# Что такое Falcor?

Tags: javascript, архитектура, reactjs

Здравствуйте.
Может, кто-то объяснит, что такое [Falcor](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/starter/what-is-falcor.html)?
Это что-то типа Reflux, Redux для react.js ? Я так понимаю, что это модель или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, к фронтенду этот проект отношения не имеет.

Falcor - middleware для приложений на Express.Js, позволяющий создать один "виртуальный json-файл на сервере", при обращении к которому клиент всего одним запросом отправляет список объектов которые он хочет получить в ответе, а сервер опрашивает все ответственные за получение этих объектов контролеры, и опять-же всего одним ответом возвращает все запрошенные данные.

Это позволяет оптимизировать передачу данных между клиентом и сервером.